# Facing 'The default FirebaseApp instance must be configured' issue in swift iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase, crashlytics

In our project, we are using muliple targets and we have enabled the Target membership to two targets for appDelegate class. While running the below podfile in multiple targets i am facing the crash issue:

```
target ‘SampleApp’ do     
 use_frameworks!
pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics', '4.5.0'
pod 'FirebaseAnalytics', '6.8.0'
pod 'FirebaseCore', '6.10.1'
pod 'FirebaseMessaging', '4.6.2'     
end          

target ‘SampleAppSDK’ do 
 use_frameworks!
pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics', '4.5.0'
pod 'FirebaseAnalytics', '6.8.0'
pod 'FirebaseCore', '6.10.1'
pod 'FirebaseMessaging', '4.6.2'     
end
```

I am able to import **FirebaseCrashlytics** in AppDelegate class and I have added the ”**FirebaseApp.configure()**” in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** function. While running the app get crashed and display the below error in the console.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'com.firebase.installations', reason: 'The default FirebaseApp
> instance must be configured before the defaultFirebaseApp instance can
> be initialized. One way to ensure that is to call `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) in the App
> Delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`
> (`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` in Swift).'

**Note:** I am able to run the project if I add the above dependencies in one target, but we are not able to see the crashes in the firebase console and we need to add the firebase dependencies to support multiple targets:

Does anyone know the issue?

Answer (score 1):

We also have multiple targets and our Podfile uses the following structure.

```
abstract_target 'AllPods' do
   target 'AppIOS' do
      pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
      pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
   end

   target 'AppTVOS' do
      pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
      pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
   end

   target 'AppWatch' do
   end
end
```

This is just an outline and is missing significant detail but is equivalent to what we first tried that worked.